# Preserving cetain entities from being encoded algorithm

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string that gets parsed through the function `encode_entities`. I need to preserve double-quotes and single-quotes from being encoded so I tried replacing these characters with a flag and then **after the encoding function call we replace the flags back with the double and single quote characters, un encoded**

Here's my strategy:

```
// this is a value in the database
my $comment = "<br/>Test<br/>[url=#|onclick="printcoupon('3569')"]test comment[/url]";
$comment =~ s/"/[dq]/g;
$comment =~ s/'/[sq]/g;
$comment = encode_entities($comment);
if(index($comment,"onclick") != -1){
 my $start = index($comment,"onclick=");
 my $length = index($comment,"\"]");
 my $newStr = substr($comment,$start,$length-$start+1);
 $comment =~ s!\[url=(.+?)\](.+?)\[\/url\]!<a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color:#336699" $newStr>$2</a>!g;
} else {
 $comment =~ s!\[url=(.+?)\](.+?)\[\/url\]!<a href="$1" style="text-decoration:none;color:#336699">$2</a>!g;
}
$comment =~ s/\[dq\]/"/g;
$comment =~ s/\[sq\]/'/g;
```

This code does not work, but its my strategy. Without these replacement calls, the end result is:

```
<a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color:#336699" onclick=&quot;printcoupon(&#39;3569&#39;)>test comment</a>
```

When it should be

```
<a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color:#336699" onclick="printcoupon('3569')">test comment</a>
```

**Also, you can see that the end double quotes for the printcoupon function text call do not exist**

I need help past this point as i am still a **very new perl user**

**UPDATE**

```
$comment =~ s/&quot;/"/g;
$comment =~ s/&#39;/'/g;
```

Seems to work but it still does not have an end double quote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to reset the values in the translation table (char2entity hash).

```
use HTML::Entities;
$HTML::Entities::char2entity{'\''} = '\'';
$HTML::Entities::char2entity{'"'} = '"';


my $comment = qq(<br/>Test<br/>[url=#|onclick="printcoupon('3569')"]test comment[/url]);
$comment  =  HTML::Entities::encode_entities( $comment);
```

Comment: I need to replace the double and single quotes with flags so after the encoding they can be replaced back as not encoded. this leaves still encoded